# convert cv::Mat to const CvMat* or CvMat*

Tags: c++, opencv

I know only **C** language, so I am getting confusion/not understanding the syntax of the `openCV` data types particularly in `cv::Mat, CvMat*, Mat.`

My question is How can I convert `cv::Mat` to `const CvMat`* or `CvMat*`, and can any one provide documentation link for difference between  `CvMat *mat` and `cv::Mat` and `Mat` in **opencv2.4**.

and How can I convert my int data to float data in CvMat ?
Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cv::Mat` has a [operator CvMat()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvmat#CvMat) so simple assignment works:

```
cv::Mat mat = ....;
CvMat cvMat = mat;
```

This uses the same underlying data so you have to be careful that the `cv::Mat` doesn't go out of scope before the `CvMat`.

If you need to use the `CvMat` in an API that takes a `CvMat*`, then pass the address of the object:

```
functionTakingCmMatptr(&cvMat);
```

As for the difference between `cv::Mat` and `Mat`, they are the same. In `OpenCV` examples, it is often assumed (and I don't think this is a good idea) that `using namespace cv` is used.

Comment: @ Thank you juanchopanza, Can you provide the link related to above operations. and how can I convert my data types in CvMat. I have the data in my CvMat is integer, Now I have to change that to float, How can I do that one?

Answer (score 0):

To answer especially [surya's second question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11027574/4575793):

TBH, the documentation on OpenCV is not the best.
[Here the link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) to the newest type: [cv::Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat). The newer types are more modern c++ like than c style.

[Here is more OpenCV forum answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/65224/conversion-between-cvmat-and-cvmat/) with a similar topic and [here is an archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20221006074640/https://answers.opencv.org/question/13437/difference-between-cvmat-cvmat-cvmat-and-mat/).
Especially for the conversion problem ([as juanchopanza mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027620/4575793)):

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_32FC1); //CV_32FC1 equals float 
                                         //(reads 32bit floating-point 1 channel)
CvMat cvMat = mat;
```

or with

```
using namespace cv; //this should be in the beginning where you include
Mat mat = Mat(10, 10, CV_32FC1); 
CvMat cvMat = mat;
```

Note: Usually you would probably work with `CvMat*` - but you should think about switching to the newer types completely. Example (taken from my second link):

```
CvMat* A = cvCreateMat(10, 10, CV_32F); //guess this works fine with no channels too
```

Changing `int` to `float`:

```
CvMat* A = cvCreateMat(10, 10, CV_16SC1);
//Feed A with data
CvMat* B = cvCreateMat(10, 10, CV_32FC1);
for( int i=0; i<10; ++i) 
    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i) 
        CV_MAT_ELEM(*A, float, i, j) = (float) cvmGet(B, i, j);
//Don't forget this unless you want to produce a memory leak. 
cvReleaseMat(&A);
cvReleaseMat(&B);
```

The first two examples (without the pointer) are fine like that as the CvMat is held on the heap then. `cvCreateMat(...)` allocates memory you have to free on your own later. Another reason to use `cv::Mat`.