# Copy data from cv::Mat to CvMat and viceversa

Tags: c++, opencv

how can i copy data from cv::Mat to CvMat and viceversa in OpenCV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert cv::Mat to const CvMat\* or CvMat\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027574/convert-cvmat-to-const-cvmat-or-cvmat)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation for cv::Mat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat), `cv::Mat` has a constructor that takes a `CvMat *` argument and an `operator CvMat()` member function.  Therefore copying between the two can be accomplished easily as follows.

```
cv::Mat m;

// populate m

CvMat n = m; // cv::Mat::operator CvMat() const;

m = cv::Mat(&n); // cv::Mat::Mat(const CvMat* m, bool copyData = false);
// or
m = cv::Mat(&n, true); // to copy the data
```

Comment: `CvMat n = m;`  don't copy data?

Answer (score 1):

According to opencv documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html):

"Backward conversion from Mat to CvMat or IplImage is provided via cast operators Mat::operator CvMat() const and Mat::operator IplImage(). The operators do NOT copy the data."